# Powershell: can't set-acl permissions of Model Folder

Tags: powershell, permissions, acl, windows-server-2012-r2

In PowerShell

I've Created a model folder and ran:

```
Get-ACL \\server\folder | % {$_.Access}
```

Here is the output for permissions I'd like to emulate:

```
FileSystemRights  : DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, Modify, Synchronize
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : CONTOSO\bgates
IsInherited       : False
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None
```

In otherwords: I went to advanced security settings for bgates and give him Full Control and unchecked "Take Ownership".

I'm trying to Input the part above in the FileSystemRights field into the script I found online (for the life of me I can't find the link) so that it can create a folder with the same permissions.

```
# this script checks to see if the folder has already been created
# if it hasn't it will create the folder then sets permissions on it
# then verifies if the folder has been created or not
# NEED TO CHANGE PATH ($Path = '\\server\folder\folder') !!!
# NEED TO CHANGE USER PERMISSION ($permission = 'UserAliasGoesHere') !!!

# this is the path for the new folder
$Path = '\\server\folder'

# test to see if folder already exists
if (Test-Path $Path) {
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow "
-------------------------------------------------------
`n
The folder has previously been created. No action taken
`n
-------------------------------------------------------
"
}
else {
# create new folder
$null = New-Item -Path $Path -ItemType Directory
# get permissions
$acl = Get-Acl -Path $path

# add a new permission (FullControl, Modify, Read)
$permission = 'bobmarley', 'Allow', 'Deletesubdirectories', 'Modify', Synchronize'
$rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $permission
$acl.SetAccessRule($rule)

# set new permissions
$acl | Set-Acl -Path $path 
# verify the folder has been created
if (Test-Path $Path) {
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "
----------------------------
`n
The folder has been created.
`n
----------------------------
"
}
else {
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Red "
--------------------------------
`n
The folder has not been created.
`n
--------------------------------
"
}
}
```

**Of course this tragically fails with the following error message:**

New-Object : Cannot convert argument "1", with value: "Allow", for "FileSystemAccessRule" to type "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights": "Cannot convert value "Allow" to type "System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights". Error: "Unable to match
the identifier name Allow to a valid enumerator name. Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again:
ListDirectory, ReadData, WriteData, CreateFiles, CreateDirectories, AppendData, ReadExtendedAttributes, WriteExtendedAttributes, Traverse, ExecuteFile, DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, ReadAttributes, WriteAttributes, Write, Delete, ReadPermissions, Read,
ReadAndExecute, Modify, ChangePermissions, TakeOwnership, Synchronize, FullControl""
At line:28 char:9
+ $rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystem ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

Exception calling "SetAccessRule" with "1" argument(s): "Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: rule"
At line:29 char:1
+ $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ArgumentNullException

**I read the error messages and of course I find no combination of my get-acl output to apply here.**

Now, Obviously, I think the problem here is that I'm not understanding how to translate the permissions I want into this script. My guesses are that perhaps this script or New-Object -TypeName is the incorrect one but I can't really find documentation for "-ArgumentList" so that I know how to plug in the permissions.

I would really appreciate it if someone can show me what I'm doing wrong here and show me the appropriate way to configure the permissions I'm looking for.

Infinite Gratitude,
Mr. Antifriese

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax used in when defining your "permission" doesn't match one of the constructors for a filesystemaccessrule object. This [MSDN site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx) has what values you need to put in what order in the Constructor section. This [TechNet Article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/josebda/2010/11/12/how-to-handle-ntfs-folder-permissions-security-descriptors-and-acls-in-powershell/) has an example. The error message basically says, this didn't work because `Allow` isn't a [`FileSystemRights`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.filesystemrights(v=vs.110).aspx) value.

Here would be your rule with the arguments in the correct syntax and order:

```
$permission = 'bobmarley', 'DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, Modify, Synchronize', 'ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit', 'None', "Allow"
```